# No puedo instalar pgadmin4 en centos 7

Tags: python, postgresql, centos7

Ingreso el siguiente código en la consola para instalar pgadmin mediante `yum -y install pgadmin4` desde el repositorio y el error es el siguiente:

```
Resolving dependencies
        -> Running transaction test
        ---> Package pgadmin4.x86_64 0: 4.13-1.rhel7 must be installed
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-web for the package: pgadmin4-4.13-1.rhel7.x86_64
        -> Running transaction test
        ---> Package pgadmin4-web.noarch 0: 4.13-1.rhel7 must be installed
        -> Processing dependencies: python-speaklater> = 1.3 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: python-psycopg2> = 2.8 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: python-crypto> = 2.6.1 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-pytz> = 2018.9 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-wtforms> = 2.2.1 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-werkzeug> = 0.15.4 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-sshtunnel> = 0.1.4 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-sqlparse> = 0.2.4 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-sqlalchemy> = 1.2.18 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-six> = 1.12.0 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-simplejson> = 3.16.0 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-psutil> = 5.5.1 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-passlib> = 1.7.1 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-markupsafe> = 0.23 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-jinja2> = 2.7.3 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-itsdangerous> = 0.24 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-wtf> = 0.14.2 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-sqlalchemy> = 2.3.2 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-security> = 3.0.0 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-principal> = 0.4.0 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-paranoid> = 0.2 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-migrate> = 2.4.0 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-login> = 0.4.1 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-htmlmin> = 1.5.0 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-gravatar> = 0.5.0 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-babel> = 0.11.1 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask> = 1.0.2 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-dateutil> = 2.8.0 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-blinker> = 1.4 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-beautifulsoup4> = 4.4.1 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-backports.csv> = 1.0.5 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-babel> = 2.3.4 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-Flask-Mail> = 0.9.1 for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: python-click for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-flask-babelex for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-python-alembic for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: pgadmin4-docs for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Processing dependencies: mod_wsgi for the package: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch
        -> Running transaction test
        ---> Package mod_wsgi.x86_64 0: 3.4-18.el7 must be installed
```

Y por ultimo tengo un error sobre dependencias

```
Resolución de dependencias finalizada         

Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-python-flask-babel-0.11.1-4.rhel7.1.noarch
     (pgdg10)
    Necesita: python-speaklater
Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch (pgdg10)
    Necesita: python-speaklater >= 1.3
Error: Paquete: 1:pgadmin4-python-flask-1.0.2-1.rhel7.noarch (pgdg10)
    Necesita: python-click
Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-python-flask-babelex-0.9.3-1.rhel7.1.noarch (pgdg10)
    Necesita: python-speaklater
Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-web-4.13-1.rhel7.noarch (pgdg10)
    Necesita: python-click
Error: Paquete: pgadmin4-python-alembic-0.9.7-3.rhel7.1.noarch (pgdg10)
    Necesita: python-editor

Podría intentar utilizar el comando --skip-broken para sortear el problema
Podría intentar ejecutar: rpm- Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Ahora mi duda es como instalo todas esas dependencias o que debería de hacer

Comment: Te faltan repositorios y por eso no encuentra todas las dependencias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esos paquetes son parte del repositorio epel, sólo tienes que añadirlo a tu lista de repositorios. El comando es sencillo:

```
yum install -y epel-release
```

Yo instalé recientemente guiándome por este tutorial:
[Install PostgreSQL and pgAdmin on CentOS 7](https://ahmermansoor.blogspot.com/2019/07/install-postgresql-pgadmin-on-centos-7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa que puedes hacer es instalar como **root**

```
# yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
```

Y luego ejecutar la instalación de este modo:

```
# yum install --downloadonly <package-name>
```

En tu caso, sería:

```
# yum install --downloadonly pgadmin4
```